# adding days on date but exclude the weekend using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to add days on dates and exclude the weekend
example: if my d1 is  = **'2018-07-06'**;then the result after adding **'2018-21-06'**,because I want exclude the weeekend.

```
 var d1 = moment($('#sDate').val()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 moment(d1).add(10,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I could not find in moment docs to exclude the weekend,can someone can help me please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of keep posting possible duplicate, can I ask you what is the solution the link that you provided!

Comment: Are you looking for me to copy/paste it? The first solution literally includes a function that does exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok try this date1= '2018-07-06' ,var d = addWeekdays(date1, 11); and log it and see the result I mean see if it exclude the weekends

Comment: I got 2018-07-23, which makes sense. If you add 11 weekdays to July 6, you get July 23.